# How to Use Regex in Selenium IDE for ID?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a changeable id like `:6g.custom-0`. This is changed always like `:7a.custom-0`.

I used this for Gmail to change themes in Selenium IDE.

[image]

I used like these are:

1. `id=regex:(.{4}custom-[0-9]{1})`
2. `css=[id$=.custom-0];`

But these are all not working...

So Please help me...

Answer (score -2):

It amazes me on how people take the time to write down their issue, but don't have the time to simply search google.

It appears you may have to use regexp:

[image]

Please follow the link:

https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-selenium-ide/

Comment: I've looked for hours cause I'm bored, and all I can find is regex may not work for the ID attribute.  I'd suggest using xpath.